# django query returns error: expected str instance, ValuesListQuerySet found

Tags: python, django, list, django-queryset

I have a script, which takes the values from the list_of_animals one by one and performs some actions with them.
 It works like this:

```
list_of_animals = ["Dog", "Cat", "Fish"]
for x in list_of_animals:
...
```

The code loops over this list, one animal at a time and finishes.

Now, for the next step, I have a model like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
animal = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True, error_messages=
{'unique':"This animal is added already."})
timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

...and a lot more animals in the SQLite database. So I try to replace that manually created `list_of_animals` with a query.

I tried to change the list_of_animals like this:

```
list_of_animals = [MyModel.objects.values_list('title', flat=True)]
```

But I'm getting **error** :

```
expected str instance, ValuesListQuerySet found
```

Actually I tried many other ways also, but without success.
 
Can you help me to find a way to replace manually created list with a query that works the same way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
list_of_animals = list(MyModel.objects.values_list('title', flat=True))
```

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

> Note that this method returns a ValuesListQuerySet. This class behaves
>   like a list. Most of the time this is enough, but if you require an
>   actual Python list object, you can simply call list() on it, which
>   will evaluate the queryset.

Comment: mu 無's answer is probably better, unless you need a proper list.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Proper list is what I needed, it seems. It worked for me ;)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing `list_of_animals = [MyModel.objects.values_list('title', flat=True)]`, do

```
list_of_animals = MyModel.objects.values_list('title', flat=True)
```

the MyModel will return an iterable list by default if you use `flat=True` with single fields list, as mentioned in [documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

> If you only pass in a single field, you can also pass in the flat parameter. If True, this will mean the returned results are single values, rather than one-tuples. An example should make the difference clearer:

```
>>> Entry.objects.values_list('id').order_by('id')
[(1,), (2,), (3,), ...]

>>> Entry.objects.values_list('id', flat=True).order_by('id')
[1, 2, 3, ...]
```

Comment: Thank you, very educational post! Almost did the work for me and I learned for the future aswell ;)